# OpenAL Sound direction

Tags: audio, openal, direction

I have a question about OpenAL. I wrote a class which optimizes work with OpenAL. I mean it provides convenient functions for work. StackOverflow, my question is about direction of sound.

When I rotate the source of sound around the listener, the sound at the bottom or top positions disappears, it is not audible. I think that at the top and the bottom point the sound should be just more quiet. I think that the sound is not directed at the listener. What should I do to make the sound be always directed at the listener when I change the position of the source in space?

change position `al.alSource3f(source[0], AL.AL_POSITION, x, y, z);`

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd be best off using an amient sound that moves with the listener/camera, like so:

```
alSourcei(alSourceID, AL_SOURCE_RELATIVE, AL_TRUE);
alSource3f(alSourceID, AL_POSITION, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [OpenAL 1.1 Specification](https://openal.org/documentation/openal-1.1-specification.pdf):

> If AL_DIRECTION does not equal the zero vector, the source is directional.

So by setting the direction to the zero vector, your source will be omnidirectional.

`alSource3f(source[0], AL_DIRECTION, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);`